# cannot invoke initializer (ARKit)

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

Trying to follow this tutorial here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tgPV_cRf2hA&feature=youtu.be&t=272

but getting the following compile error on the line

> let cubeNode = SCNNode(geometry:...
>
> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'SCNBox' with an argument list of
>   type '(width: Double, height: Double, chamferRadius: Int)'

```
import UIKit
import ARKit
import SceneKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration()
        configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    }
    @IBAction func addCube(_ sender: Any) {
        let cubeNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width:0.1, height:0.1, chamferRadius:0))
        cubeNode.position = SCNVector3(0,0,-0.2)//This is in metres
        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cubeNode)
    }

    @IBAction func addCup(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: According to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnbox/1522620-init, you have to pass width, height, **length,** and chamfer radius – and that is what the tutorial does at https://youtu.be/tgPV_cRf2hA?t=423.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the apple documentation, the constructor for SCNBox object has 4 parameters:

```
init(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, length: CGFloat, chamferRadius: CGFloat)
```

So you just need to add lenght parameter to the constructor, see API reference:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnbox

Perhaps better approach would be make constant of the object before using it in constructor for SCNNode and use intellisense:

```
let box = SCNBox(width:0.1, height:0.1,lenght: 0.1, chamferRadius:0)

let cubeNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)
```

Answer (score 0):

`SCNBox` doesn't have an initializer that takes just width, height, and chamfer radius. It has [one that takes width, height, **length**, and chamfer radius](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnbox/1522620-init).